qBittorrent is high on CPU usage and Transmission gets "peer not found" error on Server 24.04
I am running a home media server for quite some time now. Until recently I was using an old Lenovo Thinkcentre m53 with Ubuntu 22.04 and a Buffalo LinkStation NAS for storage. I was downloading using Transmission with no issues at all.
Recently I build a new "AiO" solution, using an ASRock J3355M and a Jonsbo N4 case running Ubuntu 24.04.
At first I configured Transmission as a torrent client and for some time it was performing just fine. A couple of week ago it start getting the "peer not found" error. At first it gets this error only on seeding tasks, but not for long. For some time when I paused the task and then started it again the issue was resolved. For the past couple of days this approach did not worked. So I decided to make a switch for qBittorrent(-nox). Now I do not have any issue with seeding and/or downloading, but the CPU usage is about 3 times higher than when using Transmission?! With the same number of active tasks Transmission rarely past the 40% utilization when qBittorrent do not gets below 50% at all...
I have both clients installed and with all the same task loaded on each, so I can switch between them to make comparisons.
So long story short: Transmission use less resources but regularly gets an "no peer error" and qBittrorrent works flawlessly but at a higher resources usage.
